# Laravel groupBy Database query Builder not working

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel-5

I have this problem in a query using laravel groupBy, it simply return a groupBy error. I have read the documentation about this but can't really figure it out. I also read the same problem pointing that it is because of postgreSQL that I need to include all the columns in grouBy clause. I tried it but still it doesn't return the distinct values. Please help me with this. Below is my code. Thanks a lot.

**Controller function**

```
 public function index(){
    $purchases = Purchase::groupBy('purchase_order_id')->get();
    return view('purchases/purchases_crud', ['allPurchases' => $purchases]);
}
```

**Table to query**
[image]

**Error**

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 680:
SQLSTATE[42803]: Grouping error: 7 ERROR: column "purchases.id" must appear
in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: select * from "purchases" group by "purchase_order_id"
^ (SQL: select * from "purchases" group by "purchase_order_id")
```

Comment: Can you show the error message?

Comment: Calling the model without select is returning all columns *, but you can only use columns that are inside sum() or group by. See my edit ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you have it add group by "purchases.id" or restrict the select to only the operates that are needed.

```
->select("purchase_order_id","purchases.id")

->groupBy("purchases.id") // add if possible
```

Agreggates for your case should mean something like `->select("sum(po_total)")`

---

If we group by id, we get all results as id is unique, my mistake. You want something like this

```
DB::table("purchases")->select("purchase_order_id", DB:raw("sum(po_total)"))->groupBy("purchase_order_id")->g‌​et();
```

Rule of thumb is you either select a field with Sum() or have it on the group by

Comment: The error is gone but still it returns 4 records. It should have return 2 rows right?

Comment: $purchases = Purchase::select("purchase_order_id","purchases.id")->groupBy("purchases.id")->get();
 return view('purchases/purchases_crud', ['allPurchases' => $purchases]);

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::g‌​et()

Comment: Try DB::table('purchase')->select... instead of calling the model.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset

Comment: SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column "sum(po_total)" does not exist
LINE 1: select "purchase_order_id", "sum(po_total)" from "purchases"...
^ (SQL: select "purchase_order_id", "sum(po_total)" from "purchases" group by "purchase_order_id")

Comment: ->select('purchase_order_id"', DB::raw("sum(po_total)")->group...

You read the link?

Comment: Undefined function: 7 ERROR: function sum(character varying) does not exist
LINE 1: select "purchase_order_id", SUM(po_total) from "purchases" g...
^
HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. (SQL: select "purchase_order_id", SUM(po_total) from "purchases" group by "purchase_order_id")

Comment: Look at my edit, you have to use db:raw to put sum() inside it, and both inside the select (), post the exact line that you are typing, update your question maybe.
Just follow the laravel doc link and replace table names and fields for yours