# How to use where with groupBy eloquent on Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel

I'm working on a laravel project and I'am trying to use `where` with `groupBy` on my query. The below is example of `drug_transactions` table.

```
screen_id     patient_id    drug_id
    1             1            1
    1             1            2
    1             1            3
    2             1            1
    3             2            1
```

I would like to get screen_id for `patient_id = 1`. Then I use eloquent as below.

```
    $drugtransactiongroups = DrugTransaction::where('patient_id',1)
                                        ->groupBy('screen_id')
                                        ->get();
```

My need result should return `screen_id= 1 and 2.` But I have an error as below instead.

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055
>   'zigmaclinic.drug_transactions.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select *
>   from `drug_transactions` where `patient_id` = 1 group by `screen_id`)

Any advice or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel groupBy Database query Builder not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37527279/laravel-groupby-database-query-builder-not-working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only can select fields that was used within groupBy

```
DrugTransaction::select('screen_id')
    ->where('patient_id',1)
    ->groupBy('screen_id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Dear Hung Nguyen, Thank you very much.